# Finding shortest distance on earth

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a math project for my linear algebra class.

I have been having troubles figuring out if my answers are correct. I am using the dot product to figure out the great circle distance between two locations.

The locations I choose are the Athens Airport and the Honolulu Airport in the decimal degree form which I converted to Cartesian coordinates:

the formula I used for converting to Cartesian coordinates as follows:

```
 x: r*cos(lat)*sin(lon)
 y: r*cos(lat)*sin(lon)
 z: r*sin(lat)
```

I also found this other similar formula, but I am not sure which one is the correct one:

```
  x: psinθcosφ
  y: psinθsinφ
  z: pcosθ

  where φ = longitude, θ = latitude, p = radius
```

The locations in decimal degrees for Athens Airport is (37.9364N, 23.9472E) and Honolulu Airport is (21.3156N, 157.9225W)

In Cartesian coordinates using the first formula:

```
  Athens (A)          Honolulu (B)
  x: 4592.23485179    x: -5499.87316537
  y: 2039.52598056    y: 2230.75139855
  z: 3916.80403399    z: 2316.20041505
```

Next I used those coordinates for the dot product:

$$cos\theta =\frac{a\cdot b}{||a|| ||b||}$$

$$a\cdot b=-25256709.23+7115404.634+20010078.68$$
$$a\cdot\ b=1868774.082$$

$$\left \| a \right \|\displaystyle =\sqrt(4592.23485179)^2+(2039.52598056)^2+(3916.80403399) ^2$$
$$\left \| a \right \|=6371$$

$$\left \| b \right \|=\sqrt(-5499.87316537)^2+(2230.75139855)^2+(2316.20041505) ^2$$
$$\left \| b \right \|= 8277.657476$$

$$cos\theta =\frac{1868774.082}{6371\times  8277.657476}$$
$$\cosθ =0.0354357595$$
$$\cos^{-1}=87.96925539$$

Also what is the formula to convert decimal degrees to meters?

I am not sure if this is the answer or I need a formula to calculate the great circle distance. Also I don't know if I need to find the arc in order to do this question. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first equation is wrong:

```
x: r*cos(lat)*sin(lon)
y: r*cos(lat)*sin(lon)
z: r*sin(lat)
```

Either $x$ or $y$ should have $\cos(lon)$ instead of $\sin(lon)$. It looks as if this is a what you're doing.

Is your program computing sines and cosines in degrees? You might try plugging in lat = 0, lon = 90 and seeing whether one of $x$ and $y$ comes out to zero; if not, you've got a problem: you need to convert degrees to radians.

Finally, Honolulu and Athens are almost on opposite sides of the globe, so the angle between them, even running over the north pole, is more than 120 degrees. So your answer is surely wrong.

To answer your final question: if the angle subtended at the center of the earth by rays to two points on the surface is $s$ (in degrees), then the great-circle distance between the points, assuming the earth is perfectly spherical, is 
$$
D = R\frac{\pi s}{180}
$$
where $R$ is the radius of the earth in miles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will redo this to see if it fits your stated premises. :)